# Sharing TypeScript interfaces across multiple projects

Tags: typescript

In order to try an tame Vannila TypeScript I created an npm package which exposes interfaces:

https://github.com/quantumjs/vanilla-typescript/blob/master/interfaces/IComponent.ts (A)

Now I also use this interface in other npm module:

https://github.com/quantumjs/smart-terminal/blob/master/src/SmartTerminal.ts#L1 (B)

Finally I have another project(C) that depends on B. However if I use C with typescript it will complain that module A is missing if I try import B like so:

https://github.com/quantumjs/quantumjs.github.io/blob/master/package.json#L48
https://github.com/quantumjs/quantumjs.github.io/blob/master/src/index.ts#L3

without also importing module A:

https://github.com/quantumjs/quantumjs.github.io/blob/master/package.json#L42

Is there a better solution than this?